# KMS host setup: Windows 8 and Server 2012 support

Tags: windows, windows-8, kms

As our client computer team is in the process of creating some Windows 8 images I have been charged with the setup of the KMS host to support this OS.  I do currently run a 2003 KMS host that serves Office 2010, Server 2008, and Windows 7.  However from looking at [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2691586) Technet page it would seem that I cannot install Windows 8 or Server 2012 KMS host services on Server 2003.  Am I reading that correctly?

EDIT: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/winservergen/thread/476639f4-b8ac-44fa-bc8c-f8adea542bf8

Looks like you won't activating Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012 against a 2003 KMS host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/winservergen/thread/476639f4-b8ac-44fa-bc8c-f8adea542bf8

Looks like you won't activating Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012 against a 2003 KMS host.